# Custom init parse.com

Tags: objective-c, parsing, init, parse-platform

I'm writing some class with is subclass of PFObject (Parse.com).

Example:
LBSomeClass.h

```
@interface LBSomeClass : PFObject
@propertise (strong,nonatomic) NSString* prop1;
@propertise (strong,nonatomic) NSString* prop2;
-(id)init;
-(id)initWithId:(NSString*)uid;
@end
```

LBSomeClass.m

```
@implementation LBPhoto
@synthesize prop1;
@synthesize prop2;

-(id)init {
self = [super init];
return self;
}

-(id)initWithId:(NSString*)uid {
self = [super init];
PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"someclass"];
self = (LBSomeClass*)[query getObjectWithId:uid];

self.prop1 = [self objectForKey:@"propertiseone"]; //error here
self.prop2 = [self objectForKey:@"propertisetwo"]; //error here

return self;
}
```

But when i run, there're some error:

```
[PFObject setProp1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2707d0
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFObject setProp1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2707d0'
```

Can you help me to solve that? Thanks so much!!!

**Problems solved!!!**

```
-(id)initWithId:(NSString*)uid {
self = [super initWithClassName:@"Photo"];
[self setObjectId:targetID];

[self fetch];

self.prop1 = [self objectForKey:@"propertiseone"];
// other
}
```

Comment: how you solve it.. give your solution as answer and accept that answer

Comment: here is it, thanks !!!

    -(id)initWithId:(NSString*)uid {
    self = [super initWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    [self setObjectId:targetID];
        
    [self fetch];
    
    self.prop1 = [self objectForKey:@"propertiseone"];
    // other
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems solve by me haha

```
-(id)initWithId:(NSString*)uid {
self = [super initWithClassName:@"Photo"];
[self setObjectId:targetID];

[self fetch];

self.prop1 = [self objectForKey:@"propertiseone"];
// other
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `@property (readwrite, retain)`